# iPhone and Android: Create a launcher from mobile webpage

Tags: android, iphone, html, mobile-website

I'm developing a simple mobile webpage using pure HTML5 and CSS3 for my company. My boss has asked me to make in the webpage a way to create a launcher in the user's mobile phone home screen/launcher to the website, even if with the user's authorization (without the user needing to add the website to the favorites and then creating a widget to it, in Android's case). Is it even possible? I honestly believe not, as it could be a great security breach, but I want to ask to people with more knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, for security reasons you cannot do this. On iOS as on Android, You will have to show a widget to the user begging him to add your app to his home screen.

Comment: Thanks, I liked the widget begging to the user to add to home screen :p

Answer (score 0):

On an iPhone you just tap the 'Add to Home Screen' button and the icon is added to the desktop, no drama, and no security breach.

Comment: I needed it to be an automated process, a shortcut created by the app without the user's knowledge.